# svg html string to UIImage

Tags: swift, svg

I have a svg html sting, it looks like that:

```
   let svg = """
            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="pre-logo-svg" focusable="false" viewbox="0 0 24 24" role="img" width="60px" height="60px" fill="none">
             <path fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M21 8.719L7.836 14.303C6.74 14.768 5.818 15 5.075 15c-.836 0-1.445-.295-1.819-.884-.485-.76-.273-1.982.559-3.272.494-.754 1.122-1.446 1.734-2.108-.144.234-1.415 2.349-.025 3.345.275.2.666.298 1.147.298.386 0 .829-.063 1.316-.19L21 8.719z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path> </svg>
            """
```

I want to load it into an `UIImageView`. So I convert it to data and use it in an `UIImage`

```
 let data = Data(svg.utf8)
 imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
```

but `UIImage(data: data)` is `nil`, so I use `SVGKit`library to do that

```
 let data = Data(svg.utf8)
 let svgImage = SVGKImage(data: data)
 imageView.image = svgImage?.uiImage
```

But it's same, could anyone help me on it
Thanks

Comment: Any help on it?